# Maven and JavaFX on Raspberry Pi: Loading library glass from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: maven, javafx, raspberry-pi, javafxports

I have a JavaFX app that works fine on desktop. I'm trying to "port" it to Raspberry Pi. I use the following command to run it:

```
mvn -s "/full_path/maven.xml" -Djavafx.platform=linux-arm32-monocle -Dglass.platform=monocle -Djavafx.cachedir=/full_path/cache -Dprism.order=sw javafx:run
```

It dies with the following error:

> Loading library glass from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /full_path/cache/libglass.so: /full_path/cache/libglass.so: undefined symbol: g_direct_hash
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /full_path/cache/libglass.so: /full_path/cache/libglass.so: undefined symbol: g_direct_hash
>
> ...plus many many lines of stack trace...

Looking into `/full_path/cache`, I can see that `libglass.so` is downloaded. And, to my surprise, peeking into it shows that `g_direct_hash` is also there.

I have tried all kinds of variations of `javafx.platform` and `glass.platform`, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Seems that this was caused by some kind of version mismatch. I solved it by manually downloading JavaFX instead of letting Maven get it. Had to update JavaFX dependencies in `pom.xml` to point to the local dir. Not nice but works.